# Laravel How to avoid duplicate data on update method

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a `laravel`-app where users can add social media urls to their profile. They select a network from a dropdown, let's say Facebook, and then type the url in another input field. So far so good, but it turns out, that when the user for example wants to edit just the url, an error appears, which says that the social network already exists e.g. that the user tries to duplicate it. First when both the url has changed and a different network has been selected from the dropdown, it works.
I was not aware of that error/issue and can't figure out why this happens.

here is the code snippet from my `update()` method in the Controller:

```
$query = DB::table("social_networks")
  ->where('social_networks.id', '=', request()->social_network_id)
  ->select('social_networks.name as social_network_name', 'social_networks.icon as social_network_icon')
  ->get()
  ->toArray();

  // Check if chosen social network
  // is Skype
  $result = array_filter($query, function ($item) {
    return ($item->social_network_name === 'skype');
  });

  // If chosen network is skype
  // do not check url for regex
  // else do check if regex is valid
  if (!empty($result)) {
    $validated = $request->validate([
      'url' => 'required|string',
      'social_network_id' => 'required'
    ], $errors);
  } else {
    $validated = $request->validate([
      'url' => ['required', 'regex:/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/'],
      'social_network_id' => 'required'
    ], $errors);
  }

  $user_social_network = UserSocialNetwork::where(['id' => $id, "user_id" => $request->user()->id])->first();


  //HERE IT FAILS//
  if ($user_social_network->where(["social_network_id" => $validated["social_network_id"]])->first() == null) {
    $user_social_network->social_network_id = $validated["social_network_id"];
    $user_social_network->url = $validated["url"];
    $user_social_network->save();
  } else {
    return response(['errors' => ["social_network" => ["Social network already created."]]], 400);
  }

return response(['success' => true, "user_social_network" => $user_social_network], 201);
```

Please help...

Comment: Is the `social network` and `url` specified as `unique` in your database migration at all?

Comment: @Unflux No, didn't think about that at all...